# It looks like you're using the wrong act()... but importing act and create from 'react-test-renderer'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

Losing my mind. If I import `act` from `react-test-renderer`, like the console says, I get very many "it looks like you're using the wrong act..." warnings as well as the test failing.

**TLDR: using the "incorrect" act works, results in 1 warning. Using the "correct" act (from the same library that I import TestRenderer from) does not work, results in 5 of the same warnings.**

```js
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils'; <- WHY DOES THIS WORK THEN?!

export async function wait(ms = 0) {
    /**
     * Utility function to simplify acting on async data from apollo mocked provider
     * NOTE: Console does complain about where act is imported from, although importing
     * from react-test-renderer (which is recommended in console) results in 5x the error
     * plus test fails. Will move towards better test suit soon.
     */
    await act(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        });
    });
}

it('matches its returned data snapshot', async () => {
    // NOTE I give up on trying to get the data to render with enzyme
    // the community recommends https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library
    // as the replacement to Enzyme. I will do this at some point, but for now just will stop
    // using enzyme and fall back on react-test-renderer
    const wrapper = TestRenderer.create(
        <TestWrappingComponent
            mocks={mocks}
            children={<UpdateAgenda {...mockProps} />}
        />
    );
    await wait();

    expect(wrapper.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: The messages might be coming from eslint. Can you include whether or not you use eslint and which plugin is responsible for the messages

Comment: Look up `eslint-plugin-testing-library` and see this [pull request](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/issues/259) for the name of the rule (`no-unnecessary-act`) that may be causing this warning

Comment: From what I've seen the rule is just telling you that you have used `act` wrong because you are using it to wrap a `setTimeout` instead of react-related things. See this [link](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-act.md) to read documentation on how to turn off the rule, or you can do the right thing, and fix your code to use `act` the way it was meant to be used

Comment: @smac89, from what I've gathered this is the go to way to await a mocked provider resolving... Like I mentioned in the comments I left in, lol, I might just go with testing-library and be done with it. Will checkout the eslint no-unnecessary-act thou!